# Alert dialog styling not changing multichoice items text color

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am using a style to well, style my Alert Dialog, most of it is styled as you can see below but the multichoice items are not getting the color change. I would also like to have the checkboxes in white but am not sure how to do that.

Alert Dialog:

```
android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogDarkBlue);

builder.setTitle("Faulty Part");

final ArrayList<Integer> selectedFaults = new ArrayList<>();

builder.setMultiChoiceItems(faultsList, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
            selectedFaults.add(indexSelected);
        } else if (selectedFaults.contains(indexSelected)) {
            // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
            selectedFaults.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
        }
    }
});

builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();

        onResume();
    }
});

android.app.AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.show();
```

AlertDialogBlue style:

```
<style name="AlertDialogDarkBlue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorDarkBlue</item>
</style>
```

How it currently looks:

[image]
[image]

Comment: try to extend `AppCompat.Dark` instead of `AppCompat.Light`

Comment: Yep well spotted, how would I change the checkbox selected color

Comment: sorry was afk, answered below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To fix the text color to white, just extend in your custom Style the `AppCompat.Dark` instead of the `AppCompat.Light`.
2. To edit the `CheckBoxes` selected color, you can override the `colorAccent` in your custom style and it will be applyied only to the element using that style.

This is an example:

```
<style name="AlertDialogDarkBlue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dark.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorDarkBlue</item>
    <!-- those to edit the color of checkboxes (I don't remember if both are needed or just one) -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/dialogCheckboxesColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/dialogCheckboxesColor</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/your_color</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/white</item>
```